# Resizing popup window with resizeTo is working when I type directly on console but not in the JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I google about this and tried many things but I still don't understand why resizeTo isn't working in my case.
I found that resizeTo is working when the popup is created by window.open and I respected this rule.
And this is my problem, I have a popup window which is created by window.open in a page named A.aspx.

```
 var myWin = window.open(myUrl, '', "width=400,height=250");
```

Then I tried to resize this popup by using resizeTo in another page named B.aspx.

```
<body bgcolor="white" ms_positioning="GridLayout" onload="javascript:resizePopup();">
....
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function resizePopup() {
        var targetWidth = document.body.scrollWidth + 80;
        var targetHeight = document.body.scrollHeight + 80;
        window.resizeTo(targetWidth, targetHeight);
    }
</script>
```

This is not working at all. Then I tried to resize this popup by typing directly on the console

```
 resizeTo(1000,1000);
```

but it resizes my popup. I tried the same thing to make sure on the master window page and it doesn't work like it's written in the rule. 
Then I tried to resize the popup in A.aspx just after open and this is working. So I don't really understand about this.

Anyone can explain me this? Why it doesn't work or what I understand isn't correct?

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by using parent.resizeTo.